# How to solve MixColumns

Tags: aes, block-cipher

I can't really understand **MixColumns** in the Advanced Encryption Standard, can anyone help me how to do this?

I found some topics on the internet about MixColumns, but I still have a lot of questions to ask.

Ex.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{d4} \\
\mathtt{bf} \\
\mathtt{5d} \\
\mathtt{30} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{02} & \mathtt{03} & \mathtt{01} & \mathtt{01} \\
\mathtt{01} & \mathtt{02} & \mathtt{03} & \mathtt{01} \\
\mathtt{01} & \mathtt{01} & \mathtt{02} & \mathtt{03} \\
\mathtt{03} & \mathtt{01} & \mathtt{01} & \mathtt{02} \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{04} \\
\mathtt{66} \\
\mathtt{81} \\
\mathtt{e5} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Here, the first element is calculated as

$$(\mathtt{d4} \cdot \mathtt{02}) + (\mathtt{bf} \cdot \mathtt{03}) + (\mathtt{5d} \cdot \mathtt{01}) + (\mathtt{30} \cdot \mathtt{01}) = \mathtt{04}$$

First we will try to solve $\mathtt{d4} \cdot \mathtt{02}$.

We will convert $\mathtt{d4}$ to its binary form, where $\mathtt{d4}_{16} = \mathtt{1101\,0100}_2$.

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathtt{d4} \cdot \mathtt{02} 
&= \mathtt{1101\,0100} \ll 1 & \text{(}{\ll}\text{ is left shift, 1 is the number of bits to shift)} \\
&= \mathtt{1010\,1000} \oplus \mathtt{0001\,1011} & \text{(XOR because the leftmost bit is 1 before shift)}\\
&= \mathtt{1011\,0011} & \text{(answer)}
\end{aligned}$$

Calculation:

$$\begin{aligned}
 & \mathtt{1010\,1000} \\
 & \mathtt{0001\,1011}\ \oplus \\
=& \mathtt{1011\,0011}
\end{aligned}$$

The binary value of $\mathtt{d4}$ will be XORed with $\mathtt{0001\,1011}$ after shifting if the leftmost bit of the binary value of $\mathtt{d4}$ is equal to 1 (before the shift).

My question is, what if the leftmost bit of the binary value is equal to 0, what do I XOR it with then? Ex. $\mathtt{01}_{16} = \mathtt{0000\,0001}_2$ ...?

Comment: Please don't cross post John...

Comment: I am new here so I don't know what is cross post.

Comment: @JohnPaulParreño: *Cross posting* means posting the same question to multiple newsgroups/sites/etc. In particular, posting the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites (like with [your question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232597/how-to-solve-mixcolumns)) is frowned upon, since it splits the audience in parts, each with different (and maybe conflicting answers). Welcome to Cryptography Stack Exchange, though.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to say welcome first, sorry for that :)

Comment: thanks for that, this site is very helpful to my research about AES.. wow, amazing.

Comment: @Paŭlo Eberman - I never thought that stack overflow is same as crypto.stackexchange, sorry for that.

Comment: @JohnPaulParreño It is not the same site (obviously), but is run by the same company (Stack Exchange), has a partially overlapping community, and uses the same software (with some modifications, for example we have TeX formatting here). There are quite some more sites in the Stack Exchange Network, which you can find by clicking on the Stack Exchange button on the top left.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Well, it sounds like you're close.

The multiplications implicit within the MixColumns operation are $GF(2^8)$ multiplication operations, using the same field representation as they use in the inverse within the [S-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box).

However, because they're multiplying by the fixed constants $\mathtt{1}$, $\mathtt{2}$ and $\mathtt{3}$, it's easier to implement than a general $GF(2^8)$ multiplication.

Multiplying by $\mathtt{1}$ is easy; it's exactly what you'd expect.

Multiplying by $\mathtt{2}$ is what your question is about: it is equivalent to shifting the number left by one, and then XORing the value 0x1B if the high bit had been one (where, in case you're wondering, the value 0x1B came from the field representation).  And so, that is the answer to the question you asked; if the high bit was a zero, then you don't need to XOR anything (or equivalently, you XOR in a 0x00 constant).

And, your next question would likely be "how do I multiply by $\mathtt{3}$"?  Well, you can do that by multiplying by $\mathtt{2}$ (see above), and then XORing that with the original value, since $\mathtt{3} = \mathtt{2} \oplus \mathtt{1}$.  Or, in other words:

$$\mathtt 3 \times x = ( \mathtt{2} \oplus \mathtt{1})\times x = (\mathtt 2 \times x) \oplus x $$

So, once we've gotten the multiplication by 2 operation solved, the multiplication by 3 is solved as well.

Once you've multiplied all the vector elements, then you need to add them.  Now, you might be tempted to add them modulo 256, but that'd be wrong.  This "addition" operation is actually XOR.  They've written it as $+$ because, in $GF(2^n)$ fields, XOR is considered the addition operation; it acts an awful lot like an addition operation in conjunction with the multiplication operation.

So, if we look at the calculation:

$$(\mathtt{d4} \times \mathtt{02}) + (\mathtt{bf} \times \mathtt{03}) + (\mathtt{5d} \times \mathtt{01}) + (\mathtt{30} \times \mathtt{01})$$

- $\mathtt{d4} \times \mathtt{02}$ is $\mathtt{d4} << 1$, XORed with $\mathtt{1b}$ (because the high bit of $\mathtt{d4}$ is set), giving $\mathtt{b3}$;
- $\mathtt{bf} \times \mathtt{03}$ is $\mathtt{bf} << 1$ XORed with $\mathtt{1b}$ (because the high bit of $\mathtt{bf}$ is set) and $\mathtt{bf}$ (because we're multiplying by $\mathtt{3}$), giving us $\mathtt{da}$;
- $\mathtt{5d} \times \mathtt{01}$ is $\mathtt{5d}$, and $\mathtt{30} \times \mathtt{01}$ is $\mathtt{30}$.

Now, we add (rather, XOR) $\mathtt{b3}$, $\mathtt{da}$, $\mathtt{5d}$ and $\mathtt{30}$ together, and that gives us $\mathtt{04}$.

Comment: How do you XOR the 4 values at the end together? Do you XOR the first pair, then the result with the third input, and that result XOR the fourth input? Or do you do them all in one go (i.e. output '1' if there is literally one '1' in all 4 of the inputs)?

Comment: @LoicVerrall: xor is both associative and commutative, and so you can use whatever order is convenient.  However, if you decide to xor all 4 together at once, you don't "output '1' if there is 1 in all 4 inputs", instead, it's "output 1 if there is a 1 in an odd number of the numbers"

Comment: how would you multiply 4 with X then? 4 = 2xor6 so (2 xor 6) x X. then what?

Comment: @ShantanuShinde: the most obvious way to compute $4 \times X$ is $4 \times X = 2 \times (2 \times X)$, that is, you apply the above double step twice.  Or, am I missing something.

Answer (score 5):

There's another way to perform calculations in Rijndael's Galois field $GF(2^8)$ as shown in [this video by Creel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRYHSf5A4lw). It's less optimized in terms of computational effort but stays closer to the math mentioned in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#The_MixColumns_step).

The following method works by transforming the bytes into polynomials, then multiplying them, and converting the resulting polynomial back to a byte. It's easier than it sounds as those conversions are pretty mechanical.

Let's use the numbers from your question (which also are found in the [NIST publication on AES](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.197.pdf) and [this visualization](https://formaestudio.com/rijndaelinspector/archivos/Rijndael_Animation_v4_eng-html5.html) of Rijndael at formaestudio.com):

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{02} & \mathtt{03} & \mathtt{01} & \mathtt{01} \\
\mathtt{01} & \mathtt{02} & \mathtt{03} & \mathtt{01} \\
\mathtt{01} & \mathtt{01} & \mathtt{02} & \mathtt{03} \\
\mathtt{03} & \mathtt{01} & \mathtt{01} & \mathtt{02} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{d4} \\
\mathtt{bf} \\
\mathtt{5d} \\
\mathtt{30} \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathtt{04} \\
\mathtt{66} \\
\mathtt{81} \\
\mathtt{e5} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The matrix has to go to the left of the column so that matrix multiplication is defined.

In this answer, I'll show the steps for multiplying the first column of the state with the first row of the fixed MixColumns matrix:

$$(\mathtt{d4} \cdot \mathtt{02}) + (\mathtt{bf} \cdot \mathtt{03}) + (\mathtt{5d} \cdot \mathtt{01}) + (\mathtt{30} \cdot \mathtt{01}) = \mathtt{04}$$

The centered dot $\cdot$ means multiplication over the finite field $GF(2^8)$, which ensures the results of our multiplications will fit into eight bits, one byte.

Addition corresponds to XOR in $GF(2^8)$.

## First step: $\mathtt{d4}_{16} \cdot \mathtt{02}_{16}$

Initially, convert the hex representations of our bytes to binary. You can do this with [`bc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bc.1p.html) but keep in mind that `bc` uses upper-case letters for hex digits:

```
bc <<< "obase=2;ibase=16; D4"
```

This gives us $\mathtt{11010100}_2$ for $\mathtt{d4}_{16}$.

$\mathtt{2}_{16}$ is $\mathtt{10}_2$.

We'll convert those two binary numbers to polynomials and multiply them, modulo 2.

For $\mathtt{11010100}_2$ we get this polynomial:

$\mathtt{x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x^2}$

How to convert bits to polynomials? You take the indices of the binary number where the bit is 1 and use those indices as the exponents in the polynomial.

Notice that the exponents in the polynomial correspond to the indices in the binary number where the bit is set to 1:

$
\begin{array}{c|ccccccc}
bit & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
index & \color{red}{7} & \color{red}{6} & 5 & \color{red}{4} & 3 & \color{red}{2} & 1 & 0
\end{array}
$

In $\mathtt{11010100}$, the bit at index zero is 0, so exponent 0 doesn't go in the polynomial. Same for index one, its bit is 0. But bit at index two is 1, same for the bits at indices 4, 6, and 7. Thus, we create a polynomial with the exponents 7, 6, 4, and 2: $\mathtt{x^\color{red}{7} + x^\color{red}{6} + x^\color{red}{4} + x^\color{red}{2}}$

The polynomial for $\mathtt{10}_2$ is $\mathtt{x^1}$ since the bit at index one is 1.

Alright, we converted

$\mathtt{d4}_{16} \cdot \mathtt{02}_{16}$

to

$\mathtt{(x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x^2) * x^1}$

Now we solve this polynomial multiplication modulo 2.

One way to calculate the product of polynomials is to write out the exponents of the two polynomials in a grid:

$
\begin{array}{c|c}
+ & 1 \\
\hline
2 & \\
4 & \\
6 & \\
7 & \\
\end{array}
$

And then add the exponents:

$
\begin{array}{c|c}
+ & 1 \\
\hline
2 & 3\\
4 & 5\\
6 & 7\\
7 & 8\\
\end{array}
$

Because we are in modulo 2, we need to remove all those exponents that occur an even number of times (two times, four times, etc.). But since the resulting exponents 3, 5, 7, and 8 only occur once—and 1 is an odd number—that's not necessary with this particular result.

We use those exponents to create the polynomial: $\mathtt{x^8 + x^7 + x^5 + x^3}$.

Now, convert the polynomial to a binary number: If there's an exponent in the polynomial, it means the bit at that index is 1:

$\mathtt{110101000}_2$

You can see that the bits at indices 8, 7, 5, and 3 are 1. Those indices correspond to the exponents of the polynomial $\mathtt{x^8 + x^7 + x^5 + x^3}$.

In hex, that binary number is $\mathtt{1a8}_{16}$ which is more than a byte, meaning the end result (after doing steps 2 to 5), too, might be larger than a byte which wouldn't work. In MixColumns, we transform one byte into another byte, not one byte into two bytes.

For these cases, the creators of Rijndael defined the polynomial $\mathtt{x^8+x^4+x^3+x^1+x^0}$ whose purpose is to reduce those intermediate results to a number equal to or smaller than a byte. This reducing polynomial is called $\mathtt{m(x)}$ in the literature. In other words, we subtract $\mathtt{m(x)}$ from our intermediate result $\mathtt{x^8 + x^7 + x^5 + x^3}$ to ensure the final multiplication result stays inside the finite field $GF(2^8)$.

Converting the reducing polynomial $\mathtt{x^8+x^4+x^3+x^1+x^0}$ to bits, we get $\mathtt{100011011}_2$. That's $\mathtt{11b}_{16}$ as, for example, calculated using [printf](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) and [Bash' arithmetic expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/arith):

```
printf '%x\n' $((2#100011011))
```

Since subtraction corresponds to XOR in $GF(2^8)$, we XOR $\mathtt{1a8}_{16}$ with $\mathtt{11b}_{16}$:

```
printf "%x\n" $((0x1a8 ^ 0x11b))
```

Which yields a single byte: $\mathtt{b3}_{16}$. That's the result of $\mathtt{d4}_{16} \cdot \mathtt{02}_{16}$ in Rijndael's Galois field $GF(2^8)$.

## Second step: $\mathtt{bf}_{16} \cdot \mathtt{03}_{16}$

Multiplying by $\mathtt{03}_{16}$ works the same as multiplying by $\mathtt{02}_{16}$:

Convert $\mathtt{bf}_{16} \cdot \mathtt{03}_{16}$ to binary:

$\mathtt{10111111}_2 \cdot \mathtt{11}_2$

Convert that to polynomials:

$\mathtt{(x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x^1 + x^0) * (x^1 + x^0)}$

Solve the polynomial multiplication modulo 2:

$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
+ & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 3 & 4 \\
4 & 4 & 5 \\
5 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 7 & 8 \\
\end{array}
$

In contrast to step 1, we have a couple of exponents after the multiplication that occur twice. We are in modulo 2, meaning we remove those exponents that occur two times (2 is an even number). The exponents occurring twice are 5, 4, 3, 2, and 1.

Which leaves the exponents 8, 7, 6, and 0.

Create a polynomial with the exponents that remained after modulo 2:

$\mathtt{x^8 + x^7 + x^6 + x^0}$

That polynomial in binary and hex is

$\mathtt{111000001}_2$ and $\mathtt{1c1}_{16}$.

$\mathtt{1c1}_{16}$ is bigger than a byte, so we XOR $\mathtt{1c1}_{16}$ with $\mathtt{11b}_{16}$:

```
printf "%x\n" $((0x1c1 ^ 0x11b))
```

Which results in $\mathtt{da}_{16}$. We're done with step 2.

## Steps 3 and 4

$\mathtt{5d} \cdot \mathtt{01}$ and $\mathtt{30} \cdot \mathtt{01}$ are easy because multiplication with 1 doesn't change the byte: We'll use $\mathtt{5d}$ and $\mathtt{30}$ for the final step where we XOR the four bytes from each step.

## Step 5

In the final step, we add the bytes calculated in the four previous steps:

$$\mathtt{b3} + \mathtt{da} + \mathtt{5d} + \mathtt{30}$$

Adding bytes in $GF(2^8)$ means XORing them:

```
printf "%x\n" $((0xb3 ^ 0xda ^ 0x5d ^ 0x30))
```

We get $\mathtt{04}_{16}$ which is the result we expected:

$$(\mathtt{d4} \cdot \mathtt{02}) + (\mathtt{bf} \cdot \mathtt{03}) + (\mathtt{5d} \cdot \mathtt{01}) + (\mathtt{30} \cdot \mathtt{01}) = \mathtt{04}$$

## Epilogue

If you're wondering why many implementations of MixColumns, such as the ones given on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_MixColumns#Implementation_example), use $\mathtt{1b}_{16}$ for reduction instead of $\mathtt{11b}_{16}$, [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14902/understanding-multiplication-in-the-aes-specification/95856#95856) of mine might help you.