# How does one implement the Inverse of AES' MixColumns

Tags: encryption, aes

I got an answer in the related question about [Mixcolumn for encryption](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/how-to-solve-mixcolumns), but how about decryption?

what will I do?

Because it said that I will used this:

> During decryption the Mix Column the multiplication matrix is changed
>   to:
>
> ```
> 0E 0B 0D 09
> 09 0E 0B 0D
> 0D 09 0E 0B
> 0B 0D 09 0E
> ```

How does one implement this maxtrix multiplication?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's pretty much the same as the forward Mix Column direction; it's a series of multiplications in $GF(2^8)$, however, instead of multiplying by 1, 2 and 3, you're multiplying by 9, 11, 13 and 14.

The multiplication rule isn't that complex; however, it is a bit fancier than the quick rule we got for $\times 2$ and $\times 3$.  If you're happy with doing a table lookup, [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_mix_columns) gives tables of values for $x\times 9$, $x\times 11$, $x \times 13$ and $x \times 14$.

Another way to approach it is to take the rule you already know for $x \times 2$, and use it several times, as in:

$x \times 9 = (((x \times 2) \times 2) \times 2) + x$

$x \times 11 = ((((x \times 2) \times 2) + x) \times 2) + x$

$x \times 13 = ((((x \times 2) + x) \times 2) \times 2) + x$

$x \times 14 = ((((x \times 2) + x) \times 2) + x) \times 2$

(where $+$ is addition in $GF(2^8)$; you know it better as "exclusive-or")

Further explination would require me to get into the technicalities of what multiplication in a finite field actually is; I'm not sure you're quite ready for that; if you think you might be, you might want to start in on [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic).

Comment: Thanks. It was very helpful. I have used the 2nd approach as I had implemented the multiplication by 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

For the MixColumn matrix $M$, it is true that $M^4 = I$.
So, by performing this transformation trice you get its inverse ($M^3 = M^{-1}$). A little crazy, but it might be practical in certain situations.

Comment: It would be very constructive if you convert the `As I remember` into a real knowledge with a reference or calculation. Also, you can give and compare the number of operation required to calculate the inverse and 3rd power.